# MSMQ messages not being received in private queue

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to programming and having issues with it .
I don't know why messages are not appearing in the private queue...

this is the code that i was working on but quiet not working although i have created another msmq application without async which is working but here problem arises.

```
class Program
{
   static MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        queue.Path = @".\Private$\NPQueue-Fall17-3"; 
         queue.Formatter=new XmlMessageFormatter();
        if (MessageQueue.Exists(queue.Path)==false)
            MessageQueue.Create(queue.Path);
        MessageQueueTransaction trans = new MessageQueueTransaction();
        try {
            trans.Begin();   
            queue.Send("hi1");
            queue.Send("hi2");
            throw new Exception("error");
            queue.Send("hi3");
            queue.Send("hi4");
           trans.Commit();

            Console.WriteLine(queue.Receive().Body);
            Console.WriteLine(queue.Receive().Body);
            Console.WriteLine(queue.Receive().Body);
            Console.WriteLine(queue.Receive().Body);
            Console.Read();


        }
        catch
        {
           trans.Abort();
        }
        queue.ReceiveCompleted += queue_ReceieveCompleted;
        queue.BeginReceive();
        Console.Read();
        trans.Commit();

    }

    private static void queue_ReceieveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var msg = queue.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Body);
        queue.BeginReceive();  //bar bar read kelye lagaya hai
    }
}
```

}

Comment: on removing exception still not getting messages

Comment: Hey arsalan, I am confused. Is this comment still valid? because you accepted the answer? And if it didn't solve your issue I am keen to help find an actual solution.

Comment: yes it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hardcoded a throw expection into the transaction. Which will cause, an exception, which will run an abort. With the transaction aborted, you literally aren't sending anything.